# Error when trying to export PostGIS table to FGDB in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm trying to export a layer of about 180,000ish points into a file geodatabase.  I have tried it numerous times and continually get this error.

[image: Error I'm getting]

Sometimes, it pushes 30,000 points into the feature class before it fails, sometimes 90,000 and other times 0.  As far as I can tell, the FID (OBJECT ID field) is auto generated, so I'm not sure what to do.  I've made sure that the Libs are all up to-date.

Comment: Which operating system(Windows, Linux, ...) and which QGIS version are you using? Can you save other layers as FGDB?

Comment: regarding the error message: apparently some features of your PostGIS table have very high integer values. That seems to be a problem for FGDB ...

Comment: Windows OS, QGIS Version 3.4.13.  Yes, I have be able to save other layers to FGDB.  I just did one that had about 57,000 polygons.  Jakob, I was under the impression that this error was the result of the FID being created on the export, but maybe I'm not understanding the error message.

Comment: for me it looks like that on column of your layer contains values that are too big to handle for FGDB. You could try to only export a few columns to FGDB and see if you find the column that causes problems

Comment: Good idea, I'll give that a go.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No luck.  I actually tried turning off all of the attribute columns so that only the required OBJECTID and SHAPE fields existed.  On the first export try, I got 178,412/181,706 before it hit the error.  On the second try, I got 118,933/181,706 before it hit the error.

Comment: actually I do not really know the format FGDB. Maybe there is table limit(?). Two initial ideas: maybe only export parts of the table to FGDB and merge it later (that is a bit hacky) ...  Or, if you feel comfortable with the commandline you could try `ogr2ogr` within the OSGeo4W shell. Because in the background QGIS is actually using GDAL/OGR to convert the data. It might be useful to read about the [FGDB vector driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/filegdb.html), maybe there you get some hints about the capabilities/limitations of FGDB ...

Comment: a typical command in ogr2ogr would look like this: `ogr2ogr -f GPKG output.gpkg PG:dbname="my_database" "my_table"` Find more examples [here](https://jakobmiksch.eu/post/gdal_ogr/#postgis)

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions.  I found a round about way to make it work.  Exporting to spatialite database layer, then exporting that to file geodatabase got the job done for me.  A bit of a hack but it worked.  Interestingly, when I viewed the spatialite layer, it appears that the 'ogc_fid' field created on the export has negative values (all the way to -2076704737).  Why it assigns negative feature id values is beyond me, but I'm suspecting that could be the issue with directly creating a file geodatabase feature class from the postgis table in QGIS.  An interesting tidbit.  Thanks again!